# working days between two date firebird

Tags: sql, date, firebird, between

I need to count working days between two date in firebird base(ver 2.5)

I have table(table_date) with working days (date, day--Free/Working)
and i have another table with start_date and end_date.
For example we have two dates start_date=2015-04-04 and end_date=2015-04-10
Day 2015-04-05 and 2015-04-06 are Free. 
Between this dates is 6 days but 4 is working days.

how to calculate this in base?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I would guess that something like this should work:

```sql
select a.start_date, a.end_date, 
   (select count(*)
    from working_days
    where "DATE" between a.start_date and a.end_date
    and "DAY" = 'working') as nr_of_workdays
from start_end a
```